# Finding Duplicate Algorithm - Java

Tags: java, algorithm, hashtable, hashmap

I have set of values, an arraylist, and i have to find duplicate keys. One approach is to use 2 loops. and iterate through the list for each value resutling O(n2).

the other thing, That i can do is to put the values as keys in HashTable. I believed, that hashtable would throw an exception if there is already same key in it. But it is not throwing an exception

```
    Hashtable<String, String> ht = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){
        ht.put(String.valueOf(i%10), String.valueOf(i%10));
    }
```

do i understand it wrong? Doesn't hastable/hashmap throw exception if there is already same key in it?

Comment: What does the Java documentation say?

Comment: Hashtable is a legacy class which was replaced in Java 1.2 (1998) I suggest you not use it unless you have to.

Comment: A slightly shorter way to perform the put is `ht.put(""+i%10, ""+i%10);` ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion is you want a `HashSet` instead of a `Hashtable`:

```
Set<String> ht = new HashSet<String>();

for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){
    if ( !ht.add(String.valueOf(i%10)) ) {
       //it already existed, throw an exception or whatever
    }
}
```

If you don't care about the *values* that you add to a map, you almost certainly want a `Set` and not a `Map`/table.

Comment: +1: the proper ADT to solve this problem is the *set*, not the *table*.

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't throw an exception, it simply replaces the old value. You can check if a value already exists by calling `get`:

```
if (ht.get(key) != null) {
  // value already exists
}
```

**Edit:** As @Mark Peters suggested, `containsKey` is a simpler and sometimes better solution.

Comment: How about `ht.containsKey(key)`?  The above is applicable only if you never map to the value `null`.

Comment: i can have work around, the way you wrote it. but is there any other collection or something which throws exception?

Comment: @Mark Peters: Good catch, `containsKey` is indeed a better solution.

Comment: @alee: Why do you *want* an exception?

Comment: The app i am working on already have a decent exception handling framework in place. Handling error through it would be much easier and compatible with original code rather adding if/else blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the [API docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#put%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) that `put` returns `null` if there was nothing in the table before for that key, and the key's previous value if there was one. (It doesn't throw an exception in either case.)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read up on the [performance characteristics of hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Performance_analysis).

For example, hashes will make answering the question "does this key exist?" fast, which might help with your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

According to Java Docs, the only exceptions that put may raise is NullPointerException, if key or value is null. You can change your loop to something like:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++) {
    if (ht.containsKey(String.valueOf(i%10)))
        throw new Something();

    ht.put(String.valueOf(i%20), True);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaDoc:

*put
public Object put(Object key,
                  Object value)
Maps the specified key to the specified value in this hashtable. Neither the key nor the value can be null.
The value can be retrieved by calling the get method with a key that is equal to the original key.
Specified by:
put in interface Map
Specified by:
put in class Dictionary
Parameters:
key - the hashtable key.
value - the value.
Returns:
the previous value of the specified key in this hashtable, or null if it did not have one.
Throws:
NullPointerException - if the key or value is null.
See Also:
Object.equals(Object), get(Object)*

It looks like it will let you overwrite the value, but then it gives you the old value as a return Object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the easiest way to do it:

```
List yourList;
HashSet noDuplicates = new HashSet(yourList);
HashSet duplicates = new HashSet(yourList).removeAll(noDuplicates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your memory vs runtime constraints, I would recommend something if you are space constrained:

You can sort the array (worst case of O(nlog_n) if you use something of the likes of quicksort), and then traverse it to find duplicates in adjacent elements.

Hope this helps